# How to handle LINK UNLINK verbs for expressjs

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have a simple application that supports GET POST DELETE etc. via the methods

```
app.get
app.post
app.delete
```

it seems though there is no support for the verbs `LINK` and `UNLINK`

How do I handle those verbs.

Thank you,

Comment: I am not sure but are those part of html standard. If browser does not support a particular method, often it is faked by making a standard form (POST/GET) with a hidden field having the unsupported method name. The request is then parsed and processed accordingly at the server. Do you have any links about LINK/UNLINK, never used it before.

Comment: http://en.tjcities.com/wp-content/uploads/Books/Algorithms_3rd.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using app.use of that :

```
app.use('/path', function(req, res, next){
    if (req.method === 'LINK') {
        //do stuff        
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Though it looks like these methods are totally unsupported by node. This is a module which is used by express to list supported methods: https://github.com/visionmedia/node-methods/blob/master/index.js and this is most likely the part of code of node's http parser which is responsible for detecting method: https://github.com/joyent/http-parser/blob/master/http_parser.c#L887-L901.

Comment: hmmm thank you for that link it gives me a whole new tree of things to read

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been asked ages ago, but I found no other answers, and the feature is still not documented in express. Anyway, according to this doc: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD you can type:

```
app.METHOD(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

and it appears, that the supported METHOD can be also LINK and UNLINK.